# как правильно настроить теги в select2

Tags: jquery, select

Использую для вывода тегов select2

```
$('#Todo_id_subcat').select2({
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Выберите категорию",
    allowClear: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', '.'],

    createSearchChoice: function(term) {
        return {
            id: $.trim(term),
            text: $.trim(term)
        };
    },
    ajax: {
        url: '/todo/GetCategoria2',
        type: 'POST',
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                q: 1,
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            //alert('dd');
            return {
                results: $.map(data.data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.name,
                        id: item.alias,
                        alias: item.alias
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        // alert('sd')
        var data = [];

        function splitVal(string, separator) {
            var val, i, l;
            if (string === null || string.length < 1) return [];
            val = string.split(separator);
            for (i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i = i + 1) val[i] = $.trim(val[i]);
            return val;
        }
        $(splitVal(element.val(), ",")).each(function() {
            data.push({
                id: this,
                text: this
            });
        });
        callback(data);
    }
});
```

При вводе вручную значения происходит поиск в базе данных, если не находит то я могу вставить тег со своим значением, как отменить эту функцию, что-бы не выводились варианты которых нет в базе

Comment: Думаю если убрать tokenSeparators получиться то что вы хотите.